# Python regex to match begin of string or whitespace

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following string

```
'abc[123]defgh ijk[456]lm no[78] pq'
```

And I would like to extract all parts which are either between the begin of the string and `[` or between whitespace and `[`. For the given string, these are the parts `'abc'`, `'ijk'`, and `'no'`.

I have the following expression

```
exp = re.compile(r'\s(.*?)\[')
```

But I cannot figure out how to add the beginning of the string as an optional expression. How do I have to write the expression to cover both cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
(?:^|\s)(.*?)\[
```

The start anchor (`^`) matches the beginning of the string (or line in [`MULTILINE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) mode).

Comment: Thanks, this works, and after having a look at the documentation, I understand the syntax as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another:  after finding the starting character, look for everything that is NOT a [ *and ensure it is followed by a [*

```
(?:^|\s)([^\[]+)(?=\[)
```